# create Hyperlink with docx.dll?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, docx

How to create hyperlink with docx.dll dynamically , currently tried below but not working

```
using (DocX document = DocX.Create(@"Test.docx"))
{
    // Add a hyperlink to this document.
    Hyperlink h = document.AddHyperlink
    ("Google", new Uri("http://www.google.com"));

    // Add a new Paragraph to this document.
    Paragraph p = document.InsertParagraph();
    p.Append("My favourite search engine is ");
    p.AppendHyperlink(h);
    p.Append(", I think it's great.");

    // Save all changes made to this document.
    document.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `p.AppendHyperlink("www.google.com", "Google", HyperlinkType.WebLink);`
 ?
Additionally , you can take a reference from [Insert Hyperlink to Word in C#](http://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.Doc/Spire.Doc-Program-Guide/NET-Word-Insert-Hyperlink-to-Word-in-C-VB.NET.html) .